# Columns with varying widths - one with text and one with images

Tags: two-column, width

Is there a way to make two columns in a document?

One column for images and the other for texts. But I want the column of images to be smaller than the column of text. And I want to be able to adjust later these widths.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A table, perhaps? `paracols`, should work too

Comment: Are you interested in breaking this columnar arrangement across the page boundary?

Comment: i am very new to latex, please if you have some specific examples it will ne very useful, i have to make a 5 page article that will be split in 2 columns, one for text one for image at the left of text. But i want the width of the columns to be adjustable

Comment: @tremopoulostremo: Sorry, I meant `paracol`, not `paracols`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps, using `paracol` package and the `\columnratio` macro.

Use `\columnratio{0.33,0.66}` (say) for specifying a one-third of width left column, the other one using the rest of textwidth.

`\begin{paracols}{2}` starts a two-column mode then and place the image first, then use `\switchcolumn`, followed by the text. 
In order to flush synchronize the column content (left and right start at equal positions) use `\switchcolumn*`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}

\columnratio{0.33,0.66}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{beeduck}
\switchcolumn
\blindtext
\switchcolumn*
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{beeduck}
\switchcolumn
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\clearpage
\setlength{\columnsep}{100pt}


\begin{paracol}{2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{beeduck}
\switchcolumn
\blindtext
\switchcolumn*
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{beeduck}
\switchcolumn
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Changing the vertical spacing between the images, for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}

\columnratio{0.33,0.66}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{beeduck}
\switchcolumn
\blindtext
\switchcolumn*
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{beeduck}
\switchcolumn
\blindtext

\end{paracol}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{beeduck}
\switchcolumn
\blindtext
\switchcolumn
\vskip\baselineskip
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{beeduck}
\switchcolumn
\blindtext
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes something like this. But where can i adjust the space between the two images?

Comment: @tremopoulostremo: The space is due to synchronization. If you don't want to keep left and right column in line, use `\switchcolumn` instead of `\switchcolumn*`

Comment: sorry but i dont understand the difference. I wanted to lets say these 2 ducks to your example to shown closer together. These images to have less space between. But, generally i want this space between the images to be adjustable. Because later in the document, lets say, i will want to make bigger the space between the images, later i will want to make smaller the space between the images and so on. (Sorry for my english)

Comment: Sorry, you're not providing really help to help you. A bad way would be `\vskip\baselineskip` or whatever to change the spacing, use `\switchcolumn` then

Comment: how can i adjust the space between the images in the left column?

Comment: @tremopoulostremo: See the update

Comment: ok i got it now i think

Comment: is there a way to put also a footnote at this left columns?

Comment: @tremopoulostremo: Did you ask for `footnotes` in your question above? You're changing the question, adding requirements after requirements -- this is not how TeX.SX works :-(

Comment: @tremopoulostremo: `\footnote{foo}` does work as usual, giving columnwise footnotes

Comment: the question i want to ask is very complicated so i thought i will ask step by step tasks? How else can i make this complicated question? And how else can i gain information about what i want to do? Do you think its better to post the whole task? I am a very new user of latex.

Comment: @tremopoulostremo: The problem is that you can't add one requirement after another one, complicating the whole stuff. Ask one feature in a question, then use a new question. And please use a textbook or online manual for learning LaTeX as well. We can't do everything for Learners (there's not much learning really then)